# Mathematical Arguments similar to Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, predicate-logic

I need to determine whether the following arguments are true or false.

[Argument 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSmFB.png)

[Argument 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jObBN.png)

They both look somewhat similar to the axiom of induction and the axiom of strong induction. I feel like argument 1 is valid, and argument 2 is invalid, but I have no evidence or proof. Please help.

Comment: "argument 1 is valid, and argument 1 is invalid" @_@ you have borked logic

Comment: sorry, I meant argument 2 is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Argument $2$ is invalid as you cannot get $P(2)$ from the premises.

Comment: Thank you! I understand argument 2 now!

Answer (score 0):

The first form **is** "induction".  With the second form, the result would be that "P(n) is true for all *odd* n".

Comment: Technically, the first form isn't induction, but it is easily converted to induction.

Comment: first form as in argument 1?